# Is there a way to reach the end of the AST without putting all rules?

Tags: java, c++, loops, for-loop, antlr4

I am using Antlr 4.8 and using the CPP14 Antlr Grammar in Github I upload it here because the Github page is not found [CPP grammar](https://gofile.io/d/YfZyd0).
I am trying to compare between two statements inside the for loop:
for example:

1. a[i] = a[i] + 10;
2. b[i] = b[i-1];
3. b[i] = b[i+1] +10;

each of these numbers represents an example. the reason for me comparing the statements is to do dependency analysis on them and see if it is a dependency or not.
for example:
a[i] = a[i] + 10; -> there is no dependency here because we work with same "i".
but in b[i] = b[i + 1] +10; -> there is a loop carried dependency because we are wating the value of [b + i].

in my visitor, I access to for loop and I did the following:

```
public class visitor<T> extends GrammarBaseVisitor<T> {

public static boolean status;

@Override
public T visitClassicForStatement(GrammarParser.ClassicForStatementContext ctx) {

    String str3 = ctx.statement().getText();
    String str1 = ctx.statement().compoundstatement().statementseq().statement().expressionstatement().expression().assignmentexpression().logicalorexpression().getText().toString();
    String str2 = ctx.statement().compoundstatement().statementseq().statement().expressionstatement().expression().assignmentexpression().initializerclause().assignmentexpression().getText().toString();
```

str 3 will take the full statement in it.
str 1 will be the part on the left-hand side.
str 2 will be all the part on the right-hand side.

what I did to handle the dependency is:

I used chatAt and .equal function to compare between the left-hand-side and right-hand-side.

but still not work perfectly.

my question is: how I can access what inside a single loop and nested loop and control it and do some dependency analysis on it, and see if there is a single statement inside the loop or multi statements lets say two statements and compare between them to check the dependency if exist in a single statement and multi statements, then write a comment above each loop statement, and what is the simple way to avoid these lines I used to declare the strings and reach the rule I want directly?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are programming in Java and not C++.  The C++ does not have the `boolean` type and does not use `public` outside of a class.  Please adjust your language tags as appropriate.

Comment: thank you for your comment, actually, I am coding with java but I am working on c++ antlr grammar.

Comment: Please provide a link to your CPP14 grammar. I've used both C grammars ([here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4) and [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/cpp/CPP14Parser.g4)), and there is no `classicForStatement` parser symbol. You can insert the semantic checks on any set of visitors, but you are always going to need to either navigate around the parse tree or set up attributes in a dictionary. What happens if you assign j=i-1 and use j as an array index? You will need to add data flow to your analysis.

Comment: I am sorry I edited the post and I upload CPP grammar because the GitHub page not found.

Comment: @kaby76 Can you please refer to me the part in the book that addresses the semantic checks, and how can I add the data flow to my analysis, and is it possible to use a visitor or listener to do the data flow?

Comment: @Hisham I guess what I was trying to get at is for you to decide what your requirements are. This is a long, hard problem. Usually, the parse tree would be converted into a basic block graph before starting this analysis, eg LLVM. You can do the checks in other visitors, referencing `.Parent's` and checking the context from that direction. [Dragon book](https://www.worldcat.org/title/compilers-principles-techniques-and-tools/oclc/1055658673&referer=brief_results), [Muchnick](https://www.worldcat.org/title/advanced-compiler-design-and-implementation/oclc/932262043&referer=brief_results).

Comment: I was able to see if there are multi statements inside the loop by using the same declaration above for each statement, but some declaration is so long, and I did some type of analysis on them, the maximum statements I used is three and the result of the analysis will be put in boolean. now when I want to reduce the statements in the source code, I can't and error appear https://ibb.co/vPF3cj2 this is a photo of the error.  How I can handle this error and is there any way to receive the statement with a different approach, no matter how much is the statement, and without a previous declaration

Comment: I'd like to help, but to be honest, I can't understand what you're asking.  Perhaps clarify the question?  It jumps around quite a lot.  The proximate cause of your exception is a null pointer exception in your visitor (which you've not shared).  So, you're trying to reference an optional value in your context (I would guess) without having really ascertained that it exists.  (sorry, it sounds a bit insulting to suggest that you got a NullPointerException because you tried to dereference a null, but that's about all we can tell).  Even your example code is VERY (VERY) specific to your input,